# Uploading files different servers at once using a single html Form

Tags: forms, post, upload, amazon-s3, pylons

Is there a way to make a form where it can simultaneously upload to several servers at once?

Currently in my web application, I am asking the users to type in some info + select a few files to upload.

- Title, Description, Info, etc
- File 0
- File 1
- File 2
- File ...

On the backend, I'm using Pylons. Currently it accepts POST of (info + all files), processes the info and the first file (file 0), and uploads them again to Amazon S3. I only need to process info and the 'file 0' on my own server, the rest of the files I can pass through directly to S3 via a POST.

Is there a way to make a form where the info+file0 will be POST'ed to one server, and the rest of the files be POST'ed directly to S3?

Comment: As far as I know POST can only be directed at a single target location. You could use pass through (have your form, submit itself to another form) as a way of dong it, but it sounds like thats not the route you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

While you could employ JavaScript trickery to make clicking on a submit button result in multiple POST requests to multiple servers, such a solution will almost certainly cause more problems than it solves.  You should probably stick with your current method.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369143/upload-large-files-to-amazon-s3-directly-and-add-other-date-to-database-using-we/20318266#20318266) and [this](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) out.

My solution would involve ajax upload(s) to S3 as a first step. Once you're done with the files, you can submit all the other fields (not ajax) to your webserver, eventually adding the generated S3 links.