# Upload large files to Amazon S3 directly and add other date to database using web forms and PHP

Tags: php, forms, upload, amazon-s3

I want to create a single web form where a user provides a large file, and some information like title and description. When the form is submitted, the file should be directly uploaded to Amazon S3 (without uploading it to the web server), while the information is added to the database using PHP.

How would I go about doing this? I know I could use the [direct upload post solution](http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html), but then I wouldn't be able to add the other information to the database.

Comment: not possible, unless you're running your db on amazon as well. you cannot have a single form submit to two different servers at the same time. you can use JS to duplicate the post so two copies of everything go to both places, but then you're forcing the user to upload two copies of those large files.

Comment: What if I create to forms with different IDs, one for information and one for the file. I only have one submit button and when I press submit on the file form, jQuery will serialize the information form, and use a AJAX-call to post it to a database? It's messy, but could it work?

Comment: @Chrizmo did you ever find solution to this? I'm currently attempting to do the same.

Comment: @trevoray No, I didn't. In the end the upload and providing the data in two separate steps. No automation at all.

Comment: @Chrizmo yeah, that's what I had to do too. I uploaded file first, then grabbed the etag and then had user fill out name, info and saved that w/ etag to my own database.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an ajax submit of the file on S3 (using the direct upload parameters, eventually) and then submit all the other fields to your webserver in a second step (even not ajax, of course).

You could also use an hidden field in your form to submit the new S3 link (which you can retrieve after the ajax upload is completed), since I guess you need to store it together with all the other data.